# HighChart Chart displaying incorrect data when switched to StockChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to render a HighStock chart. For some reason when I switch it to a HighStock chart it changes the labels to random data.

When you change the

```
Chart_650422 = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

[image]

into

```
Chart_650422 = new Highcharts.StockChart({
```

[image]

The xAxis labels are changed to random data.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/14we85px/

Comment: xAxis Label changed mean ?

Comment: I posted a demo for you to try...

Comment: you need this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/14we85px/2/ please see your updated fiddle at link. It has both scrollbar navigator. The issue was navigator is highstock-only feature and you didn't enabled that enabling that showing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Highstock doesn't support categorized xAxis, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis) - options `type` or `categories` are not listed.

However, you don't have to switch to Highstock - if you have highstock.js file included, then you can create Highcharts chart with enabled features from Highstock, see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/14we85px/3/ (*changes:* removed `scroolbar` (?) and added `scrollbar.enabled = true`).

Answer (score 0):

xAxis categories are not shown because you used  max:2 in xAxis , it will show only 0th,1st 2nd category. when you will comment "max"2 it will show missing category.

```
        "min": 0,
        "max": 2,
```

[Your fiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/14we85px/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but please read the question again. It says "For some reason when I switch it to a HighStock chart it changes the labels to random data.". I know about the min and max, I was adding a scroll bar when I had this issue. I am only trying to figure out why the labels change to random text.

Comment: @Hanoncs label change to random data ? the data is same , I saw. If your prob is about hyperlink missing and normal text shown use html in label like  labels": {
                "useHTML":true }

Comment: Please read the question. I will add photos.I intended to have scroll when switched to StockChart. The Min and Max are supposed to be there.

Comment: Got your point now,you need scrollbar and range selector,right?

Comment: you need this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/14we85px/2/ please see your updated fiddle at link. It has both scrollbar navigator. The issue was navigator is highstock-only feature and you didn't enabled that enabling that showing it properly.